# Is it possible to use Google AppEngine for hosting the app along with Amazon S3 for image storage?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, amazon-s3

I am planning to use Google AppEngine to host my application, but my application also requires lot of image storage (as users of application can upload multiple images).

So for storing the images I am planning to use Amazon S3.

Is it possible to use both the services together? What are the challenges?

Comment: I see only one major challenge: you may have a lot of traffic between Google's data centers and Amazon's, which may slow down your response time, and cost you money -- while keeping app and storage in the same DCs will speed things up and save money.  Why S3 instead of Google Cloud Storage, which would offer the latter advantages?

Comment: The reason for opting for Amazon S3 is that it is stable, as I have been reading, Google is planing to deprecate the Blob storage with it's cloud storage service. Also the pricing aspect for Blob storage is not very clear to me. Surely I am open to change.
Also I was thinking of calling S3 directly from the client removing unnecessary calls between the two DCs. And just to store the reference of the image in Google DataStore.

Comment: Blobstore's eventually going away (though an API on GCS emulating it will stay) but GCS is here to stay.  But if you only need storage traffic to/from the clients, not your app, then the one issue I wondered about doesn't apply to your case (I thought you might want the images service to process images -- resize, enhance, crop, &c).  GCS pricing seems pretty clear to me per https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing , as does s3's per http://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ -- but that's a commercial, not tech issue, so inappropriate for stackoverflow, let's stop here!-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but you will experience much lower latency if you will use Google Cloud Storage with [get_serving_url](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions#Image_get_serving_url) which even allows you to dynamically resize the image by simply changing the URL parameter.